# How to trigger this rare event in GTA IV - TBOGT?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv

I've played GTA IV - TBOGT Single Player on PC for a long time. But this thing is new to me.

**The event:**

I am roaming in Alderney with a six star wanted level. When I continue killing cops and destroy everything, a NOOSE Annihilator started to shoot missiles at me. I never encounter this event. After reloading and starting a new six star chase and destroying many choppers, It never happened again.

So, How can I trigger the NOOSE Annihilator to shoot missiles at me?

Answer (score 5):

If I remember correctly, the cops will not fire the guns of the helicopter in GTA IV.  I cannot find any evidence to support that they do fire the guns at times or missiles for that matter.

The Ballad of Gay Tony added the Buzzard Attack Helicopter which was equipped with rockets, but the police use the Annihilator to pursue players, which does not have any rockets.  In [this video](https://youtu.be/s4cVzx7m3nQ), the player has a 6 star wanted level and the helicopters pursuing him/her were Annihilators, none of which opened fire with their miniguns.  You can also tell they are playing TBoGT because of the colorful menu in the beginning on the video.

That being said, the Annihilator was upgraded in TBoGT to have explosive rounds as [the wiki says](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Annihilator#Performance):

> The Annihilator is upgraded in The Lost and Damned and The Ballad of Gay Tony, where it moves more quickly and fires explosive rounds instead of the regular ones seen in Grand Theft Auto IV.

If anything, it was these explosive rounds you saw, but not rockets.

Comment: I am really sure It was rocket . Because the first shoot not killing me (armor cheat :D) but the second blow me up. It happens near a bridge connecting Alderney and Algonquin.

Comment: If it was indeed explosive rounds, how do I make the cops shoot me with this?

Comment: As I said, I cannot find any evidence supporting that this can occur.  I don't think it is possible.   Its more likely you witnessed something else that caused explosions.  Since you're on PC, there are probably some mods out there that you can use to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

It is for sure a rocket volly as I have been in a highspeed pursuit and multiple times, sometimes when I'm in an area like an open area or stretch of road clear with no civilians in area, I start to suddenly be shot at by a volly of 6-8 missiles which most times straight end the chase, however, the helicopters were not facing me. I even had a time where there was no helicopter near me when rockets went off and got me. It is a strange and neat event.